# AppleScriptingBridge for Music app not returning sources

Tags: applescript, itunes, macos-catalina

With the advent of Catalina OSX, iTunes has been removed from OSX, instead a Music app has been introduced, apparently similar but exclusively for music content with podcast etc.

Following code written in Objective C does not return any sources from the music, iTunes object.
Similar code worked for iTunes. but is not working for new Music app of apple.

Please advise, any experts.

```
MusicApplication* music = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.music"];  

NSArray *sources = [music sources]; 
// sources are empty, zero length array always
for (MusicSource *source in sources)
{        

    SBElementArray *userPlaylists = [source userPlaylists];

    for(MusicUserPlaylist* playList in userPlaylists)
    {      }
}
```

Comment: Actually ScriptingBridge is dead for many, many years.

Comment: ScriptingBridge is buggy and crippled, but it’s not dead (alas). OP has probably enabled hardened runtime (Xcode does this automatically when updating the project) but not checked the option to allow sending Apple events.

Comment: There is no hardened runtime section in my target

Comment: It would be under “Signing & Capabilities”. Have you added an `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` entry to your `Info.plist`? Depending on what you’re doing, you might also consider using the [iTunesLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ituneslibrary?language=objc) framework.

Comment: @foo After adding NSAppleEventsUsageDescription to info.plist and enabling events in hardended runtime it works now. Thank you.